# Tagging people in comments

Tags: support

I do not know if this is the right place to ask the following question, but couldn't find the answer anywhere else either. So please delete the question if it is out of scope for this community.

I have a question which I asked on MMSE some time back. Today I went to one of the answers and tried to add a comment to which I wanted to tag the person who answered. However I was unable to do so as adding the `@` symbol and typing the name didn't show the user name of the person. Is there a specific time limit within which tagging can be done? Or is this something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "I wanted to tag the person who answered"

It can take some time to become familiar with the Stack Exchange tagging system, because I agree with you that it doesn't always work the way we would expect based on other platforms with tagging functionality.

When commenting on a person's own post (in this case, their answer), the author of the post is automatically tagged (they will get pinged in their notifications for all comments, by default).

So instead of typing a comment like:

> "@PBH, can you add more detail?"

you can just write something like:

> "PBH, can you add more detail?"

and they will still get pinged.

Comment: However when trying to tag you in this answer, typing `@Nike Dattani` didn't show the user account. Any idea why that is so?

Comment: That's exactly what I mean. I'm pinged automatically, so there's no need for the @.

Comment: Oh I get it now. Thanks